# Magento 2 : Add to cart button change to go to cart after adding product

Tags: magento2, template, addtocart, ajax, jquery

How to do the following -

Clicking on "Add to Cart" button adds the product to cart then Button Changes to "Go to Cart" and clicking on that redirect to Shopping Cart

Please help me in doing this functionality.

Comment: are you want after product add dierctly go to checkout page?

Comment: @ Vinay , In which page do you want this requirement ? Inproduct list page or in product details page ?

Comment: To achieve this, first check your current product id is present in the quote. If so display a button named "Go to Cart" with cart link in it, otherwise display the usual "Add to Cart" button.

Comment: @Rakesh want this functionality on product page. After product add "Add to Cart" Button Replaces with ""Go to Cart" Button and "Go to Cart" Button Redirect to Shopping Cart.

Comment: @MeGento Want this functionality on Product Details Page. Could you please help me a bit more. Like which code i have to add.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your add to cart button in

```
app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view
addtocart.phtml
```

With

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <?php
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $quoteId = $objectManager-> create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuoteId(); 
            $cartData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository')->get($quoteId)->getAllVisibleItems();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
            $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); 
            $count=0;
            foreach($items as $item) {
                if($item->getProductId() == $_product->getId())
                {
                    $count++;
                }
            }

                if($count != 0){?>
                    <button type="button"
                            title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Go to Cart') ?>"
                            class="action primary tocart"
                            id="product-addtocart-button"
                            onclick="window.location='<?php echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart');?>'">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Go to Cart') ?></span>
                    </button>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                    <button type="submit"
                            title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                            class="action primary tocart"
                            id="product-addtocart-button">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
                    </button>
            <?php } ?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Do i need to replace whole addtocart.phtml. I have added this code by replacing this     
    <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" style="width: 100%; font-size: 1.6rem;"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">

            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
but Go to Cart button is not showing up after add to cart is clicked

Comment: I have replaced the code with the above code. But After "add to cart" ajax starts adds the product and after ajax same "Add to Cart" comes up. No "Go to Cart" is coming on product page.

Comment: Cleared Browser Cache, Cleared Magento Cache and Static Files, But still "Add to Cart" Ajax runs and same "Add to Cart" Comes Up

Comment: Yes i have refreshed the page, but still no luck. Still "Add to Cart" Coming

Comment: Yes, Exact addtocart.phtml is edited. path with template hints 

app/design/frontend/theme/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Same path file is edited but Still having same issue. Is there anything need to done with the js ?

Comment: Can you add some explanations as to why your code works please? Simply adding a template won't really help most people as they can't replace their existing template if it's already been customised.

Comment: Actually the above code works after i clearing cache....I think i have taken cart collection from session...Trying another solution for your question

Comment: New Updated Code Removed "Add to Cart" Button from Product Page. Old code Still Displaying "Add to Cart"

Answer (score 0):

Actually its updating buttons caption (whatever set in phtml) in this js file after add to cart pressed.

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/mage226/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

On category pages buttons have different captions. like: `"Add to Cart", "Back Order", "Pre Order"`
To preserve same caption you have to provide it in this js file.
For that you have to extend this JS file using [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) way.

For that You have to follow following way:

In your custom module you have to add dependency:

1) app/code/LevoSoft/PreOrder/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'LevoSoft_PreOrder/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can create file as following in your custom module:-

2) app/code/LevoSoft/PreOrder/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($, $t) {
    "use strict";

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', widget, {

            disableAddToCartButton: function(form) {
                this.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector).find('span').text();// Here you are getting current buttons caption and assigning it to re-render it whatever the caption is. thats it
                this._super(form);// Now calling parent function
            }
        });

        return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
    }
});
```