# Magento 2 Change 'Add to Cart' button to 'Go to Cart' after product is added to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, ajaxaddtocart

I have tried to achieve this using answer from the question here [Magento 2 : Add to cart button change to go to cart after adding product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199697/magento-2-add-to-cart-button-change-to-go-to-cart-after-adding-product)

However the button text is not changed immediately as the code is from phtml file and not js file.

I wish to achieve this using js(catalog-add-to-cart.js). 
To check if product is added to cart, I need to get cart items in this file. How do I get current user cart items here?
Once the text is changed to Go to Cart, I also want to change the button link to cart url.

Answer (score 0):

***override catalog-add-to-cart.js***

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

***in your theme***

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/test/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

*line around 211  change*

**$t('Add to Cart'); to  $t('Go to Cart');**

```
setTimeout(function () {
                var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Cart'); //change here

                addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
                addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextDefault);
                addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
            }, 1000);
```

***after run command via ssh :***

```
rm -rf pub/static/*;rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*;rm -rf var/cache/*;rm -rf var/log/*;rm -rf var/di/*;rm -rf var/page_cache/*;rm -rf var/tmp/*;rm -rf var/generated/*;rm -rf generated/*;

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```